# reading data from text file into struct, then print the data

Tags: c++

Hey guys i am writing a program that reads in data from a file and stores it in a struct and i have a couple problems. The text file looks like:

```
Azrin, Neil
2.3  6.0  5.0  6.7  7.8  5.6  8.9  7.6
Babbage, Charles
2.3  5.6  6.5  7.6  8.7  7.8  5.4  4.5
```

the first number in the line is the difficulty level and the next 7 numbers are scores, goes on for 24 different names.

My program will print all the divers names followed by the difficulty levels. Then it will only print the first score for diver # 1, not all of the scores.

also, for diver #2's scores it prints out the second score (3rd number in line) and not the first score (2nd number in line). and so on for each diver.

how can i make it so it will read and print all of the scores for each diver?

ive been working on this for hours so any help is much appreciated!

my code:

```
for (lcv = 0; lcv < NUM_NAMES; lcv++)                    //reads in all of the data
{
getline(inFile, diveList[lcv].diversName);

inFile >> diveList[lcv].diff;

for (count = 0; count < NUM_SCORES; count++)
{
inFile >> diveList[lcv].scores[count];              //the problem may be here on down below where i print out the data... im not sure
}

inFile.ignore(200, '\n');

}

printTableOne (diveList);




void printTableOne (const diverList diveList)
{
int lcv;
int count = 0;
cout << "The number of divers for round 1 is: " << NUM_NAMES << endl << endl;

for (lcv = 0; lcv < NUM_NAMES; lcv++)
{

cout << "Diver #" << lcv << endl;
cout << setprecision(1) << fixed <<  endl;
cout << "NAME: " << diveList[lcv].diversName << endl;
cout << "DIFFICULTY LEVEL: " << diveList[lcv].diff << endl;
cout << "SCORES: " << diveList[lcv].scores[lcv] << endl;     //problem here??

cout << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen and what happens instead? Have you tried debugging/poor mans' print debugger?

Comment: The same [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042748/outputting-data-from-a-file-into-structs-and-arrays-of-structs/16043365#16043365)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed in the line

```
cout << "SCORES: " << diveList[lcv].scores[lcv] << endl;
```

Here you only print one score, and it uses the same index as for the diver. And since you have more divers than scores, pretty soon you will be printing scores from *outside* the array.

You need a loop here, just like when you read the scores from the file.

Comment: thanks for your response ive tried putting a for loop : for(count = 0; count < NUM_SCORES; count++) and changed scores[lcv] to scores[count] and it just gives a score of 0 to everyone. is there a while loop i can use to detect the end of the line? or im not sure what to add here. thanks again

Comment: @user2309306 You might want to learn how to use the debugger. Then step through the code line by line checking that it does what you expect it to.